# jQuery Ajax JSON Return Single Variable Plus Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

> **NOTE:** This question has been down-voted three times now, yet no one provides a reason for the down votes. That is helpful to no one in
>   the community. Do not let that deter you from the great answers by
>   both Anurag and Phil, below.

I am retrieving data using Ajax, json. The database may return no results, one record, or multiple records. I need to know the number of rows when I receive the data. If only one row, it will simply fill the form. If multiple rows, the user is directed to a list in order to make a selection.

To explain in more detail, the number of rows are stored in the $Rows variable in the PHP file, which comes from the result of the query, which is not necessary to show. There was a query, This is the code that comes after it. So, expressing my question in other words, what I need to know is how to send the $Rows variable back to the jQuery function along with the multidimensional array. If that is still not understandable, please see the comments in those specific sections.

Basically, after query, my PHP looks like this:

```
$Rows = mysql_num_rows($Result);
if($Rows == 1)
{
    $P = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
    $Output = json_encode($P);
}
elseif($Rows > 1)
{
    $x = 0;
    while($ProgRow = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
        // Of course, I could add the $Row var here, but I would need
        // To add it to each row, which seems a little daffy
        $P[$x]['ID'] = $ProgRow['ID'];
        $P[$x]['ProgCode'] = $ProgRow['ProgCode'];
        $P[$x]['ProgName'] = $ProgRow['ProgName'];
        $x++;
    }
    $Output = json_encode($P);
}
else
{
    $P = json_encode(0);
    $Output = $P;
}
echo($Output);
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$.ajax(
{
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'scripts/UtilAjax.php',
   data: 'Sec=EditPrograms',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data,status)
   {
      // ideally what needs to happen here is to be able to
      // return the $Rows variable as well, to determine how
      // To deal with the return data.
      console.log(status);
      console.log(data.ID+' '+data.ProgCode+' '+data.ProgName);
   }
});
```

Comment: `$ProgRow["ProgCode"];` you must enclosed `keys` with quotations.

Comment: Pretty minor criticism for an example for something that has nothing to do with the question. Are you the person who downgraded me?

Comment: (Which may only cause someone who actually might have an answer to ignore the question) Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Downgrading without an explanation is really revolting. I see nothing at all wrong with this question. If either of the two people who have downgraded this question had any integrity, they would explain why the hit and run.

Comment: I need to know the number of rows when I receive the data. If only one row, it will simply fill the form. If multiple rows, the user is directed to a list in order to make a selection. The rest is explained on the comments, where it is more easily understood. It is also expressed in the question title.

Comment: Solution is not complicated.....always send an array and check it's length. For no results send empty array

Comment: First of all i did not downgrade you (if you are referring to me) and my comment is not criticism (if you are also referring to me also). Im just trying to point what you might have missed so maybe you could start with that.

Comment: @charlietfl  That isn't quite going to work with an associative array, is it? Basically, if I can just detect whether the array is associative or not, that would do the trick.

Comment: @jerome - Sorry, Jerome. The downgrades had me irritated, and you responded almost right away, so I jumped to conclusion. No problem.

Comment: you aren't creating associative array when #rows > 1 so don't do it for the other conditions either

Comment: Humm - Can't really think of a way to do that without creating an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not sure if this is what you want but from what I understood, you want to get the `$row` data and `$output` data in the ajax. In that case, just send back the two in an json encoded associative array.

```
echo json_encode([$rows, $Output]);
```

Finally, in the client side,

```
success: function(data, status) {
  console.log("Output: " + data.Output.ID + ' ' + data.Output.ProgCode + ' ' + data.Output.ProgName);
  if (data.rows == 0) {
    // do something ...
  } else if (data.rows == 1) {
    // populate the form
    console.log(data.output.ID + ' ' + data.output.ProgCode + ' ' + data.output.ProgName);
  } else {
    // multiple rows
    // display the select list
  }
}
```

Comment: Using  var stuff = json.parse(data);
console.log(stuff); Gives me a "json is not defined" for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: use `JSON` not `json`

Comment: With `dataType: json`, the `data` will have already been parsed. It does not need to be parsed again

Comment: That's good to know, because I get a syntax error when trying to use it and the data appears okay to me.

Comment: Oh, I guess it's a jquery thing. I missed that.

Comment: So now I'm getting closer, put it doesn't seem to be handling the array correctly. Seems like it should. My test is not with the multidimensional, just a standard key->value array. The result is 
Object { Rows: 1, Output: {…} } I'm afraid I really don't know how to parse that out , though. data.Output gives me [object Object]

Comment: My Error!  All is now working. Thank you all for your help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @ Anurag Daolagajao please edit the client success function and I will accept it for the answer. This worked: console.log("Output: "+data.Output.ID+' '+data.Output.ProgCode+' '+data.Output.ProgName);

Comment: Nevermind - it just dawned on me that I can edit it, so I did. I guess it has to be reviewed before it appears.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, just return an array of results, no matter how many. This makes your API consistent and results in less code.

For example

```php
$out = []; // start with an empty array
while($ProgRow = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
    $out[] = $ProgRow; // push onto the array
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($out);
exit;
```

Now your result will always be an array with zero or more records. Your JS can then simply check the length to determine how many results there are

```js
$.post('scripts/UtilAjax.php', {
  Sec: 'EditPrograms'
}).then(data => {
  console.log('Number of results:', data.length)
  switch(data.length) {
    case 0:
      // handle no records
      break;
    case 1:
      fillOutForm(data[0]) // use the first record
      break;
    default:
      showList(data)
  }
})
```

---

In order for jQuery to know the response is JSON, you should either add the correct `Content-type` response header (as above), or force the response to be parsed via

```
$.post('scripts/UtilAjax.php', {
   Sec: 'EditPrograms'
}, null, 'json').then(data => ...)
```

or

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'scripts/UtilAjax.php',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {Sec: 'EditPrograms'},
  dataType: 'json'
}).then(data => ...)
```

Comment: Ah - I was trying to figure out how to get the length of a multidimensional but, as you point out in your case structure, it really isn't necessary. Seems like no matter how may nests there are, length should return the number of top arrays, but, unless I screwed up somewhere, it doesn't seem to.  I like this.

Comment: I accepted  Anurag's answer because I already had it working before I saw yours and, in trying yours, I am having a problem with the JavaScript length function. Not sure why. This looks like some really efficient code, though, so I will continue to try to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't really understand the data.length problem at all. In a 1 record (22 fields) response, it is showing a length of 512. That may or may not be the number of characters. The data is fine, though.

Comment: @RationalRabbit did you add the `header('Content-type: application/json')` part to your PHP? 512 is probably the length of the JSON string. You're getting a string because jQuery doesn't know it's JSON